# How to update the cherry picked commit on gerrit?

Tags: git, gerrit, git-rebase, git-pull, git-cherry-pick

I made a commit `A` to a branch. It's not merged yet. My friend cherry picked my commit and made a new commit `B`. Now they form a relation chain right? So, If I amend my commit `A`, What is the best way to get my new changes in my friend's branch?

PS: On amending the commit, the commit hash will change and create a new patchset.

Comment: The commits are not related in Git. Gerrit has a change-ID that can relate otherwise-unrelated commits, but whether you should *use* this to *mark* them as related, I don't know. None of the Git commands know or care about this Gerrit change-ID; it's specific to Gerrit (which I have not used myself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a good practice cherry-picking a commit from a open change, but if this was needed, now it's necessary to cherry-pick the new commit, amend the original commit and push to Gerrit, creating a new patch-set.

Comment: I thought this is a common occurance in gerrit workflow. but anyways.

Comment: The best practice is always to base your work on merged changes, this includes not cherry-picking open changes, but sometimes it's not possible to wait for some change to be submitted.

Answer (score 1):

I think your friend did cherry-pick on gerrit web site.
When A is updated, just cherry-pick again on gerrit web site, and it will create new patchset on commit B.

ps, don't abandon commit B.